# python nosetests are failing

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to run nosetests. I have a virtual env created under twolex. I installed dogpile.core and dogpile.cache . When I run nosetests, it throws up the following error:

```
File "/home/test/.virtualenvs/twolex/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dogpile/cache/region.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .. import Lock, NeedRegenerationException
ImportError: cannot import name Lock
```

I can see Lock.py under site-packages/dogpile . These are default packages.  version=0.6.2

The permissions on all the files looks right. I've recreated this a few times, but still see the same error. Is there something else I need to set or modify or install to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just dealt with this. Apparently, `dogpile.cache` now supersedes `dogpile.core`, and this is not documented very well. Uninstall `dogpile.core`, and make sure `dogpile.cache` is at least 0.6.